# hadoop, when run under spark, merges its stderr into stdout

Tags: hadoop, process, apache-spark, pyspark

When I type

```
hadoop fs -text /foo/bar/baz.bz2 2>err 1>out
```

I get two non-empty files: `err` with

```
2015-05-26 15:33:49,786 INFO  [main] bzip2.Bzip2Factory (Bzip2Factory.java:isNativeBzip2Loaded(70)) - Successfully loaded & initialized native-bzip2 library system-native
2015-05-26 15:33:49,789 INFO  [main] compress.CodecPool (CodecPool.java:getDecompressor(179)) - Got brand-new decompressor [.bz2]
```

and `out` with the content of the file (as expected).

When I call the same command from Python (2.6):

```
from subprocess import Popen
with open("out","w") as out:
    with open("err","w") as err:
        p = Popen(['hadoop','fs','-text',"/foo/bar/baz.bz2"],
                  stdin=None,stdout=out,stderr=err)
print p.wait()
```

I get the exact same (correct) behavior.

**However**, when I run the same code under **PySpark** (or using `spark-submit`), I get an *empty* `err` file and the `out` file starts with the log messages above (and then it contains the actual data).

[**What am I doing wrong?**](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-7898)

**NB**: the intent of the Python code is to give the output of `hadoop fs -text` to another program (i.e., passing `stdout=PIPE` to `Popen`), so please do not suggest `hadoop fs -get`. Thanks.

**PS.** When I run `hadoop` under `time`:

```
from subprocess import Popen
with open("out","w") as out:
    with open("err","w") as err:
        p = Popen(['/usr/bin/time','hadoop','fs','-text',"/foo/bar/baz.bz2"],
                  stdin=None,stdout=out,stderr=err)
print p.wait()
```

the `time` output correctly goes to `err`, but `hadoop` logs incorrectly go to `out`.

I.e., **`hadoop` merges its `stderr` into its `stdout` when it runs under spark**.