# How to I map over an RDD locally?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

As a follow-up to [my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30467502/850781), how do I map over an RDD locally, i.e., collect the data into a local stream without actually using `collect` (because the data is far too large).

Specifically, I want to write something like

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
with open('out','w') as out:
    with open('err','w') as err:
        myproc = Popen([.....],stdin=PIPE,stdout=out,stderr=err)
myrdd.iterate_locally(lambda x: myproc.stdin.write(x+'\n'))
```

How do I implement this `iterate_locally`?

- does *NOT* work: `collect` return value is far too large:

  `myrdd.collect().foreach(lambda x: myproc.stdin.write(x+'\n'))`
- does *NOT* work: `foreach` executes its argument in a distributed mode, *NOT* locally

  `myrdd.foreach(lambda x: myproc.stdin.write(x+'\n'))`

Related:

- [Spark: Best practice for retrieving big data from RDD to local machine](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21698443/850781)

Answer (score 1):

What about `RDD.foreachPartition`? You can work on the data in batches, like this:

```
myRdd.foreachPartition(it => it.collect.foreach(...))
```

If you look at the [feature request history](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/spark-users/LUb7ZysYp2k), `RDD.foreachPartition` was created to straddle this middle ground.

Comment: is it guaranteed to process _sorted_ RDD _in order_?

Comment: I believe so -- believe this is the basis of `RDD.zipWithIndex`, which lets you create the equivalent of an AUTO INCREMENT index of type Long on your RDD. And I know `RDD.zipWithIndex` preserves the original ordering of the RDD.

Comment: I get `pickle.PicklingError: Cannot pickle files that are not opened for reading`: apparently, `foreachPartition` is still executed in a distributed mode, so `myproc.stdin` has to be picked and shipped (and it is obviously impossible).

Comment: Hmm. I guess that makes sense. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 1):

Your best option is likely to save the data to a source that your local machine can access and then iterate over that.

If that isn't an option, and assuming your local machine can handle one partitions worth of data at a time, is you can selectively bring back one partition at a time (I'd cache the data first) and then do something along the lines of:

```
rdd.cache()
for partition in range(0, rdd.numPartitions):
  data = rdd.mapPartitionsWithIndex(lambda index, itr: [(index, list(itr))]
  localData = data.filter(lambda x: x[0] == partition).collect
  # Do worker here
```

Comment: I am sorry, I don't understand what you mean by "source".

Comment: I also added a quick snippet if you don't want to do that.